# iOS - What controller is this app using to display the date and controls to move forward and backwards by one date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKW6y.jpg

At the top is a UINavigationController with the title fitbit and a button on the right for editing.

Below is a controller that displays the current date and has buttons to the left and right to move forwards or backwards one date.

Would this be another UINavigationController or something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't personally use Fitbit so I'm not speaking from physical experience, but based off the picture it looks like they are doing the following :

They are using a `UINavigationController` for sure. This automatically creates the Navigation Bar at the top, where you can add the 'edit' button. This also creates a 'back' button when you click on a `UITableViewCell` to navigate back to the main tableView. The cells look like their row height is set to about 100 or so. The date header is simply a custom tableView header which you can set by doing the following :

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:datePickerView];
```

or for a specific section :

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
}
```

And then the tabs? How can you add tabs to a `UINavigationController`? Easy. All you have to do is click on all different 4 tabs respective `UINavigationController` (dashboard, challenges, friends, account) and go to your Xcode menu bar and select :

Editor > Embed In > and then select Tab Bar Controller

So to answer your question, it looks like to me it's a combination of both `UINavigationController` & `UITabBarController`.
**NOTE** this can be done numerous ways, i'm just offering a way of how it could be done to emulate it, you won't know the exact way they do it.

Instead of creating my own tutorial for you, here are some good ones to skim through to get you started:

**Embedding :** http://www.appcoda.com/storyboard-tutorial-create-tab-bar-controller-and-web-view/

**Setting a custom tableview header** : http://www.accella.net/custom-header-and-footer-views-for-uitableviews/

That one goes through a couple options but it's easier just to use `self.tableView setTableHeaderView:` can be implemented anywhere and uses minimal code.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right here. I can say that because I tried myself to just add a label underneath the UINavigationController and above the UITableView in my own project and it looked nothing like the fitbit app.

Answer (score 1):

No this would be a custom view with a `UILabel` displaying the date and two `UIButton` changing the date.

Comment: Why is this the correct answer? What about the table? Doesn't that give you a hint? And the tab bar either?

Comment: This is what was asked.  Below is a controller that displays the current date and has buttons to the left and right to move forwards or backwards one date?

Comment: Exactly. _controller_ is the key word in the OPs question. Your answer was a custom view. Even though the title of this question is poorly written for SEO, the chance a new developer or beginner lands on this can be misled by that. You didn't say anything about a controller. All views are custom if you think about it, but what's displaying the views, (tableViews, tabBar, navigationBar)

Comment: It's not wrong. But it's not right either @ManuelManningtonTheThird  . I'm just offering them to fix it, but if they don't I'll offer an answer tomorrow. You don't have to uncheck this as the right answer I'm just simply encouraging them to elaborate on what they initially answered for a more clear and concise explanation. It's a very vague answer that's why I down voted. If you take their answer and try to recreate it in IB you won't be able to is my point because they offered no controller references

Comment: @soulshined: I would be thankful to you if you can help us with this. Since I am not getting what exactly you want me to explain, You please edit this answer the way you want the things to be explained so that it becomes useful for everyone.